# ruby inheritance syntax - passing arguments to the base class

Tags: ruby

When creating models for the sequel database gem in ruby a syntax like this is used:

```
class Users < Sequel::Model(:users) # <= what method is getting called here?
 # other stuff...
end
```

Where `:users` is the name of the table.

I would like to pass an argument to the base class like this when the child class is defined for one of my own classes, but I can't work out how to do it. I don't know what this syntax is called, and I couldn't find any examples of it in my googling. I tried looking at the source for Sequel::Model as well, but its such a big class I couldn't find the relevant section.

Does anyone how what this syntax is and how it works?

Comment: One thing to consider: Do you really want to use syntax that's so arcane, you have trouble finding it yourself? Might be worth going with something a bit more mundane (but which other maintainers could more easily understand in the future). Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common trick to make a normal class/module method call look like a parameterized type.

There is actually a module method `Sequel::Model` which takes a single argument and returns a class (see [the source code](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib%2Fsequel%2Fmodel.rb#L39)).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the `#inherited` hook of Class?

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited

From the docs in the link above:

```
class Foo

  def self.inherited(subclass)

   puts "New subclass: #{subclass}"

  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

class Baz < Bar
end
```